# How do i display the maximum temperature and minimum?

Tags: c#, winforms

My program display the temperature of the GPU-video card every x seconds.
I want that it will display each time the minimum temperature and maximum temperature.

For example the temperature was: 49c 
Then it changed to 51 and then to 45 and then to 49 again.

So maximum is was 51 minimum was 45.
If the temperature will raise above 51 then the maximum will be change to it.
And same for minimum.

```
private void timer_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if (textBox3.Text == "")
            {
                timer.Stop();
                MessageBox.Show("אנא הכנס נתונים בתיבות הטקסט מצד שמאל כדי להמשיך");
            }
            else
            {
                timer.Start();
                Computer computer = new Computer();
                computer.Open();
                computer.GPUEnabled = true;

                foreach (var hardwareItem in computer.Hardware)
                {

                    if (hardwareItem.HardwareType == HardwareType.GpuNvidia)
                    {
                        foreach (var sensor in hardwareItem.Sensors)
                        {
                            if (sensor.SensorType == SensorType.Temperature)
                            {
                                sensor.Hardware.Update();
                                //textBox1.Text = String.Format("The current temperature is {0}", sensor.Value);
                                temperature_label.Text = sensor.Value.ToString() + "c";
                                label8.Text = sensor.Value.ToString() + "c"; // to save the last maximum temperature to a external variable and then show it in label8 same for the minimum temperature \\
                                label8.Visible = true;
                                int t = temperature_label.Text.Length;
                                if (t > 3)
                                {
                                    temperature_label.Location = new Point(238, 200);
                                }
                                timer.Interval = 1000;
                                if (sensor.Value > float.Parse(textbox3_value))
                                {
                                    Logger.Write("The current temperature is ===> " + sensor.Value);
                                    button1.Enabled = true;
                                    //  temperature_label.ForeColor = Color. // to check wich colors to use blue and red regular state and in emergency when its over 90c ?! what colors for each label ?
                                }
                                this.Select();
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
```

I have a timer tick event where i update the temperature .
In label8 i want to display the maximum. 
Now the way it is its just showing the temperature at real time.

Comment: April Fools' day is not today, right?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just add two variables to store maximum and minimum temperature:

```
double minTemp = Double.MaxValue,maxTemp = Double.MinValue;
```

And :

```
double value = Convert.ToDouble(sensor.Value);

if(value < minTemp) minTemp = value;
else if(value > maxTemp) maxTemp = value;

lblMin.Text =  minTemp.ToString() + "c";
lblMax.Text =  maxTemp.ToString() + "c";
```

Comment: How about `Int.MAX_VALUE` and `Int.MIN_VALUE` instead of a `bool` to control for first values?

Comment: Good. Now..according to the OP, `sensor.Value` already returns a number, and it seems to be a `float`...

Comment: then we can use  float.MinValue and  float.MaxValue, or even better: double =)

Comment: Why `double` instead of `float`?

Comment: because i don't know returning value type, double has more range than float,though we talk about temperature, it can't be too much like that anyway

Answer (score 0):

You probably want three labels and three variables:

```
  // Example
  tempCurrent = sensor.Value;
  if (tempMax < tempCurrent)
    tempMax = tempCurrent;
  if (tempMin > tempCurrent)
    tempMin = tempCurrent;

  lblMax.Text = tempMax + "c";
  lblMin.Text = tempMin + "c";
  lblCurrent.Text = tempCurrent + "c";
```